# How to ignore error when click on add Selenium JAVA

Tags: java, selenium

How to ignore error when i click on add button although the value is exist? 
Kindly advise

```
public void clickOnOK() {
        switchToFrame(getFrames(FRAME_TYPE.rcp_content));
        //setElementValue(get(By.partialLinkText("OK")), null);
        this.imageClick(By.id("btnAddNewRowOk"));
        //dismissAllDialogs();
        sleep(3);
        browserSession.switchToPreviousOpenedBrowser(); 

    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Please can you provide either the URL or sample HTML of the page you are working with, and the error you are receiving?